# Activity crashes, but only if launched from the lockscreen, and only if landscape is forced?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, landscape, lockscreen

I have an activity that launches on the lockscreen, similar to an alarm. However, if I set that activity to landscape only in AndroidManifest, the app will crash on launch.

If I remove the landscape only designation, it launches without an issue.

Additionally, if I launch it as landscape only, but not from the lockscreen, it also has no issues.

What about launching it in landscape from the lockscreen would cause this?

The error I get, is that one of my variables running in an async thread is Null.

Again, no problem doing the same thing in portrait from the lockscreen and bno problem staying in landscape, but not launching from the lockscreen.

Comment: Can you post your async implementaion

Comment: Shoot, I was wrong. I mean, it could be something with the async thread, but it's actually just an integer variable that goes from accessible in on create  to null when it crashes.

Comment: It's an integer that *is* accessed from asyncringtoneplayer(I think that's what it's called), among other things